# is there a timestamp when specific column has changed Mysql/Joomla?

Tags: mysql, joomla

Is there anything like this , a function or query that tracks the time when the row was last changed ? id dont have timestamp column nor can I add one , there is specific column , name publish that is changing from 0 to 1 and vice versa and I would like to check the time when it was changed last.

working with joomla here , and trying to figure out when plugin is published/unpublished , there is no event for that , only events we have are onExtensionBefore and after save , but no event that tracks publish state.

Comment: can u add another table?

Comment: no I cant , I can only check existing one and it has no published time column

Comment: @diEcho I edited my post so you would understand better what I am dealing with

Comment: suggestion : if you ask this one on joomla forum, you will get better answer ( i think so )

Comment: lol , don't get me started on that , joomla forum gets no reply's on stuff like this

Answer (score 1):

Add trigger that executes on every `columnname` update:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER `TriggerName` 
    AFTER UPDATE ON `TriggerTable` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        IF NEW.columnname <> OLD.columnname THEN
            SET `timestampcolumn`=NOW();
        END IF 
    END
    |
```

After that if you do update `columnname` it should update `timestampcolumn` to current time.

***Note:*** Change your delimiter with `DELIMITER [`*`delimiter`*`]` when defining triggers. Delimiter should be something that is not inside `CREATE TRIGGER` definition. Default delimiter is `;` and changing it from default is required because `;` after `SET ´timestampcolumn´=NOW();` would otherwise break `TRIGGER` definition.

Comment: like said , cant add / change columns

Comment: @Benn Then you need to store that information somewhere else, like other table, other database, file, sketch book...

Answer (score 0):

For onSave events you should be getting the whole row of data including the published/state status. You should not need a special trigger for each field that might be involved in the save.
I would make a content plugin with  that has a table keyed to the table in question that would grab the time on save if the state is changed.

Comment: the problem is that the plugin we are making is system plugin and onSave is for content plugins only

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Any form that saves is going to have an onSave. So you can use a content plugin, but if you want to use a system plugin you can ... but why is it that you would want to check that plugin on every load when you know it should only be triggered when you are editing a form in the admin?
What else is it that you want the plugin to do? Also what version of Joomla are you on?

Comment: User can disable the plugin within extensions Plug-in Manager: Plug-ins, without going in to plugin edit form , and there is no event I can hook on to , testing on 25/3.0 , making css/js compression plugin. On plugin form enter , we delete cache and new one is made , but we cant do that if user disables plugin within plugins list. SO a timestamp that tells us when plugin was disabled/enabled can help us cross reference timestamp of the cached files and delete the cache if unpublished time is newer than cached file timestamp.